# Django-toolbar not working

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm trying to add django toolbar to my project, and I've done all the steps said in manual, but the toolbar is not working. There is a yellow bar in the top of the page which has a big "Signals" inside, and ajax_loader under it. and the div which contains ajax_loader is over the other contents of page!

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$.cookie('djdt')') - @alecxe

Comment: which version of Django and the toolbar are you using?

Comment: @mbrochh Django 1.7.1 and toolbar 1.2.2

Comment: I have just created a new django project via `django-admin.py startproject testproject` and added `debug_toolbar` to INSTALLED_APPS. Then I have started the server via `./manage.py runserver` and I can see the toolbar when I visit `localhost:8000`. You can try these few steps yourself. If it doesn't work for your existing project, it means that you are using something like django-cms or you have misconfigured your STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL settings. It might help if you could post the content of your main `urls.py`.